# How to find array with array of array

Tags: javascript

`let result = []` 
I have array `const arr = ["A", "B"]` 
and array of array
`const arrOfArr = [["A","C"],["A","B"],["B","C"]]` 
I want find arr in arrOfArr, if exist will push "Pass" to result
my code:

```
 arrOfArr.forEach((el) => {
        if (JSON.stringify(arr) === JSON.stringify(el)) {
          arrResult.push("Pass");
        } else {
          arrResult.push("False");
        }
      });
```

but If condition is not true will push many False to result 
What solution for me if condition is not true just push 1 False to result?

Comment: Why all the `stringify` stuff? That can be quite wasteful in terms of garbage produced.

Comment: You can use [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: The linked answer is terrible. Don't use that, outdated af

Comment: JSON.stringify has been demonstrated to be faster than any other solution. No garbage produced. If you want only a result you can just use `arrResult.push(arrOfArr.some(...) ? 'Pass' : 'False')`